# Resource intensive simulations running in a microservice architecture

Tags: c#, architecture, microservices

I've been reading about microservices lately and I'm really starting to get won over by it. I would like to migrate an application to use microservices, but there is one part of our system that I'm unsure really fits with the pattern.

The application we are developing lets users start long running simulations that can run for weeks. The simulations are fed by real time data and are very resource intensive  (a beefy desktop could run 2 or 3 simulations at a time). One user can start multiple simulations, and many users can get access to and view the results as they evolve. The simulations have to keep running even when the users are logged out.

How would something like this fit into the microservice pattern?

Comment: i'd say one service to manage the simulations, and one service to run them - ideally auto-scaled, so you start one service instance per simulation and remove it after it's done and results are exported. although i'd say: if the simulation is reasonably _complex_, it won't be a _micro_-service by definition.

Comment: I was just blown away by running the eShopOnContainers demo project in Visual Studio and seeing all the dependencies, sqlserver, mongdb, redis and 10+ other services just being spun up and having it all run with 1 click. I just thought 'I want that!' Today we spend a crazy amount of time just getting the development environment up. Same thing in production. We spend way to much time deploying to new servers. Having it all scale automatically seems like a dream. As long as it's not an anti-pattern and we are not shooting ourselves in the foot I'm fine with it not being a micro-service per say.

Comment: that's not a software problem you're describing, but a cultural one. no single technical decision will have any impact on this - except rigorously switching to CI/CD. once set up, deploying _is_ just pressing one button. but what you _want_ to do most is enforce _documentation_ in your team.